# Prevent view to layout Subviews

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout

I've designed a UIViewController in a .xib file. It uses Autolayout.

I have in it a UISlider which change the text of a UILabel when its value change : I've linked the sent event "Value changed" to my header file and then implements the function in the .m file of my controller. This method only changes the text of the label, depending of the value of the slider.

When the view appears, the slider is not show (set outside of the screen). I present it on the view using animations. 
The problem is when I change the value of my slider, it calls automatically

```
 -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
}
```

And unfortunately, it reset all the subviews of my controller's view to their original positions.

How to present the slider to "destroy" the actual layout.

**EDIT**

My slider's connections in the interface builder :
[image]

and the code of the associated function :

```
- (IBAction)sliderDureeValueChanged:(id)sender {
    dureeMois = (int) sliderDuree.value;
    if (sliderDuree.maximumValue == sliderDuree.value)
    {
        [lblDuree setText:@"Max"];
    }
    else if (sliderDuree.minimumValue == sliderDuree.value)
    {
        [lblDuree setText:@"Min"];
    }
    else
    {
        [lblDuree setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d month",dureeMois]
    }
}
```

**EDIT2**

Here is the stack obtained with `[NSThread callStackSymbols]` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` when called by using the slider.

```
2013-07-16 16:39:47.420 MyApp[2363:907] Stack trace : (
    0   MyApp                               0x0003cd5f -[GraphiqueFVViewController viewDidLayoutSubviews] + 50
    1   UIKit                               0x34f938c9 <redacted> + 456
    2   QuartzCore                          0x34d3dd8b <redacted> + 214
    3   QuartzCore                          0x34d3d929 <redacted> + 460
    4   QuartzCore                          0x34d3e85d <redacted> + 16
    5   QuartzCore                          0x34d3e243 <redacted> + 238
    6   QuartzCore                          0x34d3e051 <redacted> + 316
    7   QuartzCore                          0x34d3deb1 <redacted> + 60
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x3315d6cd <redacted> + 20
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x3315b9c1 <redacted> + 276
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x3315bd17 <redacted> + 742
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x330ceebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x330ced49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104

    13  GraphicsServices                    0x36c922eb GSEventRunModal + 74
    14  UIKit                               0x34fe4301 UIApplicationMain + 1120
    15  MyApp                               0x00021add main + 116
    16  libdyld.dylib                       0x3b264b20 <redacted> + 0
```

and backtracing all in the debug area :

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x2503, 0x00101d46 MyApp`-[GraphiqueFVViewController viewDidLayoutSubviews](self=0x1ed972f0, _cmd=0x3541247c) + 42 at GraphiqueFVViewController.m:386, stop reason = breakpoint 2.1
    frame #0: 0x00101d46 MyApp`-[GraphiqueFVViewController viewDidLayoutSubviews](self=0x1ed972f0, _cmd=0x3541247c) + 42 at GraphiqueFVViewController.m:386
    frame #1: 0x34f938c8 UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 456
    frame #2: 0x34d3dd8a QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 214
    frame #3: 0x34d3d928 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 460
    frame #4: 0x34d3e85c QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 16
    frame #5: 0x34d3e242 QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 238
    frame #6: 0x34d3e050 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 316
    frame #7: 0x34d3deb0 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 60
    frame #8: 0x3315d6cc CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    frame #9: 0x3315b9c0 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 276
    frame #10: 0x3315bd16 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 742
    frame #11: 0x330ceebc CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
    frame #12: 0x330ced48 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
    frame #13: 0x36c922ea GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 74
    frame #14: 0x34fe4300 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1120
    frame #15: 0x000e6a84 MyApp`main(argc=1, argv=0x2fd1bd18) + 116 at main.m:16
    frame #16: 0x3b264b20 libdyld.dylib`start + 4

  thread #3: tid = 0x2903, 0x3b31b648 libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent64 + 24
    frame #0: 0x3b31b648 libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent64 + 24
    frame #1: 0x3b2544f0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_invoke + 796
    frame #2: 0x3b246df8 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$up + 36

  thread #5: tid = 0x2b03, 0x3b31aeb4 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 20
    frame #0: 0x3b31aeb4 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 20
    frame #1: 0x3b31b04c libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 40
    frame #2: 0x3315d044 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 128
    frame #3: 0x3315bda2 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 882
    frame #4: 0x330ceebc CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
    frame #5: 0x330ced48 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
    frame #6: 0x390cd504 WebCore`RunWebThread(void*) + 444
    frame #7: 0x3b284310 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 308

  thread #7: tid = 0x241f, 0x3b31aeb4 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 20
    frame #0: 0x3b31aeb4 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 20
    frame #1: 0x3b31b04c libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 40
    frame #2: 0x3315d044 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 128
    frame #3: 0x3315bda2 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 882
    frame #4: 0x330ceebc CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
    frame #5: 0x330ced48 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
    frame #6: 0x33a1b3d4 Foundation`+[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 308
    frame #7: 0x33a9ee84 Foundation`__NSThread__main__ + 972
    frame #8: 0x3b284310 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 308

  thread #8: tid = 0x2d03, 0x3b32b594 libsystem_kernel.dylib`select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
    frame #0: 0x3b32b594 libsystem_kernel.dylib`select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
    frame #1: 0x331611f6 CoreFoundation`__CFSocketManager + 678
    frame #2: 0x3b284310 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 308

  thread #11: tid = 0x3003, 0x3b32b08c libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 24
    frame #0: 0x3b32b08c libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 24
    frame #1: 0x3b27cd2e libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_cond_wait + 646
    frame #2: 0x3b27caa4 libsystem_c.dylib`pthread_cond_timedwait + 44
    frame #3: 0x37088c74 JavaScriptCore`WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 108
    frame #4: 0x3719a556 JavaScriptCore`JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 82
    frame #5: 0x371acfaa JavaScriptCore`WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 14
    frame #6: 0x3b284310 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 308

  thread #12: tid = 0x3103, 0x3b31aeb4 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 20
    frame #0: 0x3b31aeb4 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 20
    frame #1: 0x3b31b04c libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 40
    frame #2: 0x3315d044 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 128
    frame #3: 0x3315bda2 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 882
    frame #4: 0x330ceebc CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
    frame #5: 0x330ced48 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
    frame #6: 0x39167d06 WebCore`WebCore::runLoaderThread(void*) + 142
    frame #7: 0x371acfaa JavaScriptCore`WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 14
    frame #8: 0x3b284310 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 308

  thread #15: tid = 0x3403, 0x3b32b08c libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 24
    frame #0: 0x3b32b08c libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 24
    frame #1: 0x3b27cd2e libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_cond_wait + 646
    frame #2: 0x3b286f18 libsystem_c.dylib`pthread_cond_wait + 40
    frame #3: 0x37088c46 JavaScriptCore`WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 62
    frame #4: 0x392e1e8c WebCore`WTF::PassOwnPtr<WebCore::StorageTask> WTF::MessageQueue<WebCore::StorageTask>::waitForMessageFilteredWithTimeout<bool (WebCore::StorageTask*)>(WTF::MessageQueueWaitResult&, bool (&)(WebCore::StorageTask*), double) + 56
    frame #5: 0x392e1e40 WebCore`WebCore::StorageThread::threadEntryPoint() + 124
    frame #6: 0x371acfaa JavaScriptCore`WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 14
    frame #7: 0x3b284310 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 308

  thread #17: tid = 0x3903, 0x3b32bd98 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 8
    frame #0: 0x3b32bd98 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 8
    frame #1: 0x3b279cfa libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_workq_return + 18
    frame #2: 0x3b279a16 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 366

  thread #18: tid = 0x3b03, 0x3b32bd98 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 8
    frame #0: 0x3b32bd98 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 8
    frame #1: 0x3b279cfa libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_workq_return + 18
    frame #2: 0x3b279a16 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 366

  thread #19: tid = 0x3707, 0x3b32bd98 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 8
    frame #0: 0x3b32bd98 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 8
    frame #1: 0x3b279cfa libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_workq_return + 18
    frame #2: 0x3b279a16 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 366
```

Comment: you want the controller subviews to maintain original positions, or have the slider "destroy" the controller subview layout?

Comment: Well... my slider is a "parameter". Out of the screen when the view appears, I make it appear by pressing a button. This button and the slider are animated using the method : `animateWithDuration:animations:^{}` of the UIView class. When changing the value of the slider, I want both of the slider and the button to stay where they are (Not useful to have a slider disappearing when modifying it, isn't it?)

Comment: this is a UISlider ? can you show the code called when the slider is modified?

Comment: Yes it is. See edit for code...

Comment: could you include a stack trace of the viewDidLayoutSubviews method being hit when you change the slider value?

Comment: I'm curious why did you not just breakpoint viewDidLayoutSubviews for the stack trace? This is a tough one because viewDidLayoutSubviews should not be called due to a slider value change. There must be something else going on. Not sure how much I can do without seeing more of the code and project.

Comment: But isn't it called because the text of my UILabel changed and the view controller want to layout subviews because of the autolayout of the view?

Comment: the text change wouldn't affect the size of the UILabel automatically.  Neither would it trigger Auto Layout to resize it or other views. You would need to trigger that programmatically

Answer (score 2):

Hey super late to the party here but we had relatively the same issue and I wanted to shed a little light on it.

We had 3 views contained in our main view: a label, a view containing login fields, and a view containing a facebook button.  When you pressed a button it would toggle between the 2 login views and when it encountered an error, the label would scale to 0, switch the text, then scale back up to 1.  We found that when the label animated and changed size, the constraints would be reapplied and the first view would be toggled back into position.

We found that the documentation for "didLayoutSubviews" says it gets called on the parent of a view when that view changes bounds.  We're assuming that it also counts as changing the bounds when you modify the transform of the view.

So the problem is that if a view animates, it will cause all of its sibling views to reposition to their original states.

We fixed this by putting the label inside of its own view.  When it animates, it calls "layoutSubviews" on its parent, which only lays out itself.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I've solved my issue since I posted it. The problem was because of the constraint animate the view just move them, and event that have an impact on the superview (like adding a subview, presenting a viewcontroller, autorotations...) reset the constraint. The solution was to add references to the constraints, change their value, ask the superview to layout its subviews and update constraints.

Comment: This helped a lot thanks! It was causing huge memory problems for me as I was dragging a view with a gesture and layout subviews was continuously getting called and putting it inside of another view solved the memory issues for me.